# MySQL explain - require index suggestions / feedback

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, indexing, vtiger

I have a database containing around 5million rows and am having issues with a query taking a long time (over a minute). I was hoping this information would be enough for someone to give me some suggestions, if I need to post more information just let me know.

Thank you in advance for any advice

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count( * ) AS count
FROM vtiger_time
INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_time.timeid
INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentityrel ON ( vtiger_crmentityrel.relcrmid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
OR vtiger_crmentityrel.crmid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid )
LEFT JOIN vtiger_users ON vtiger_users.id = vtiger_crmentity.smownerid
LEFT JOIN vtiger_groups ON vtiger_groups.groupid = vtiger_crmentity.smownerid
WHERE vtiger_crmentity.deleted =0
AND (
    vtiger_crmentityrel.crmid =211294
    OR vtiger_crmentityrel.relcrmid =211294
)


+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type        | possible_keys                                   | key            | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_crmentityrel | index_merge | crmid,relcrmid                                  | crmid,relcrmid | 4,4     | NULL                           |  5881 | Using union(crmid,relcrmid); Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_crmentity    | ref         | PRIMARY,deleted,deleted_2,crmentity_multi_index | deleted_2      | 4       | const                          | 84424 | Using where; Using index                 | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_users        | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY        | 4       | crm.vtiger_crmentity.smownerid |     1 | Using index                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_groups       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY        | 4       | crm.vtiger_crmentity.smownerid |     1 | Using index                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_time      | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,timeid                               | PRIMARY        | 4       | crm.vtiger_crmentity.crmid     |     1 | Using index                              | 
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Additionally these are my currently set indexes

```
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| vtiger_crmentity |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            1 | crmid       | A         |      755968 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          0 | crmid                      |            1 | crmid       | A         |      755968 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crmentity_IDX0             |            1 | smcreatorid | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crmentity_IDX1             |            1 | smownerid   | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crmentity_IDX2             |            1 | modifiedby  | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | deleted                    |            1 | deleted     | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | deleted                    |            2 | smownerid   | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | smownerid                  |            1 | smownerid   | A         |         199 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | smownerid                  |            2 | deleted     | A         |         199 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | deleted_2                  |            1 | deleted     | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | deleted_2                  |            2 | smownerid   | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | smownerid_2                |            1 | smownerid   | A         |         385 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | smownerid_2                |            2 | deleted     | A         |         758 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crm_ownerid_del_setype_idx |            1 | smownerid   | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crm_ownerid_del_setype_idx |            2 | deleted     | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crm_ownerid_del_setype_idx |            3 | setype      | A         |         613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crmentity_multi_index      |            1 | crmid       | A         |      755968 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crmentity_multi_index      |            2 | smownerid   | A         |      755968 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentity |          1 | crmentity_multi_index      |            3 | deleted     | A         |      755968 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table               | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| vtiger_crmentityrel |          1 | crmid    |            1 | crmid       | A         |      223960 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_crmentityrel |          1 | relcrmid |            1 | relcrmid    | A         |       12442 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

+--------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| vtiger_users |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | id            | A         |          39 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_users |          1 | idx_user_name |            1 | user_name     | A         |          39 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_users |          1 | user_password |            1 | user_password | A         |          39 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+--------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| vtiger_groups |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | groupid     | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_groups |          1 | groupname           |            1 | groupname   | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_groups |          1 | idx_groups_123group |            1 | groupname   | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| vtiger_time |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | timeid   | A         |      591772 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_time |          0 | timeid   |            1 | timeid   | A         |      591772 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_time |          1 | relatedto   |            1 | relatedto   | A         |        1405 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_time |          1 | date_start  |            1 | date_start  | A         |        7129 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_time |          1 | relatedto_2 |            1 | relatedto   | A         |        3269 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

+------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| vtiger_timecf |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | timeid   | A         |      591324 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_timecf |          0 | timeid   |            1 | timeid   | A         |      591324 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| vtiger_timecf |          1 | timeid_2 |            1 | timeid   | A         |      591324 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

After adding the following index

```
ALTER TABLE vtiger_crmentity ADD INDEX TMP_deletion_smownerid_crmid (smownerid, deleted,crmid);
```

The new explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type        | possible_keys                                                            | key            | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_crmentityrel | index_merge | crmid,relcrmid                                                           | crmid,relcrmid | 4,4     | NULL                           |  5891 | Using union(crmid,relcrmid); Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_crmentity    | ref         | PRIMARY,crmid,deleted,deleted_2,crmentity_multi_index,_deletion_crmid | deleted        | 4       | const                          | 84424 | Using where; Using index                 | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_users        | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                  | PRIMARY        | 4       | crm.vtiger_crmentity.smownerid |     1 | Using index                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_groups       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                  | PRIMARY        | 4       | crm.vtiger_crmentity.smownerid |     1 | Using index                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_time      | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,timeid                                                        | PRIMARY        | 4       | crm.vtiger_crmentity.crmid     |     1 | Using index                              | 
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What indices do you have?  I'm not sure how smart mySQL's optimizer is, but putting the two id values in the `WHERE` clause into the join conditions may help some (on both joins).

Comment: Unfortunately I can not alter my query (this is an extension for an existing system). I must also admit, I do not know what "indices" are?

Comment: And I realised what indices are, the question is now updated with this information.

Comment: what's with all of the duplicate keys?

Comment: Dev system where failures were not cleaned up it seems. These should not effect performance of this query in any dramatic way.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the query would help, but since you cannot do that, you may benefit from a composite index on `vtiger_crmentity.crmid` and `vtiger_crmentity.deleted`.  But since it isn't using one of the the index you currently have on `vtiger_crmentity.crmid`, it might not use that new one.  If it doesn't, try adding `vtiger_crmentity.crmid` to the `vtiger_crmentity.deleted` index.  Since it is already using the index on `vtiger_crmentity.deleted`, this will make the index a covering index so the query will not need to read from the table.

As I mentioned in my comment, there are a lot of duplicate indexes.  The won't affect the query for this question, but they will slow down inserts and increase table size.  The following indexes are redundant:

```
vtiger_crmentity.crmid
vtiger_crmentity.smownerid
vtiger_crmentity.smownerid_2
vtiger_crmentity.deleted_2

vtiger_groups.idx_groups_123group

vtiger_time.timeid
vtiger_time.relatedto_2

vtiger_timecf.timeid
vtiger_timcfe.timeid_2
```

You also shouldn't need the index on the user password column since you shouldn't be looking for users by password.

Comment: Thanks for your advice G-Nugget, I added the following indexes and have seen no change in performance. If you can confirm this is actually what you meant that would be great, I am by no means a mysql guru.

  ALTER TABLE `vtiger_crmentity` ADD INDEX `TMP_deletion_crmid` (`crmid`, `deleted`);
  ALTER TABLE `vtiger_crmentity` ADD INDEX `TMP_deletion_smownerid` (`smownerid`, `deleted`);

Comment: did the `EXPLAIN` change?  The second index I mentioned should be on `deleted,smownerid,crmid`.

Comment: Yes, I have ammended the new explain to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this index:

```
ALTER TABLE vtiger_crmentityrel ADD INDEX ix_crmentityrel_crmid_relcrmid (crmid,relcrmid);
```

This should allow the first row in the explain to be satisfied completely by the two indexes on the crmentityrel table and should save you a few thousand lookups.

All other parts of the execution plan are using covering indexes so if this doesn't help, I'm not sure there is much more you can do without restructuring the data or the query.